# Kubernetes cluster does not run after reboot

Tags: kube-apiserver

If I use the kubectl command after a reboot, I will receive an error. 
    x.x.x.x: 6443 was refused-did you specify the right host or port?

If I check my container with docker ps, kube-apiserver and kube-scheduler are turned on and off.

Why is this happening?

```
root@taeil-linux:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# cd
root@taeil-linux:~# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 10.0.0.152:6443 was refused - did you     specify the right host or port?
root@taeil-linux:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@taeil-linux:~# docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID                CREATED             SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                v1.15.3                 232b5c793146        2 weeks ago         82.4MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver            v1.15.3                 5eb2d3fc7a44        2 weeks ago         207MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler            v1.15.3                 703f9c69a5d5        2 weeks ago         81.1MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.15.3                 e77c31de5547        2 weeks ago         159MB
node                                 carbon                  c83f74dcf58e        3 weeks ago         895MB
kubernetesui/dashboard               v2.0.0-beta1            4640949a39e6        2 months ago        64.6MB
weaveworks/weave-kube                2.5.2                   f04a043bb67a        3 months ago        148MB
weaveworks/weave-npc                 2.5.2                   5ce48e0d813c        3 months ago        49.6MB
kubernetesui/metrics-scraper         v1.0.0                  44390ebe2b73        4 months ago        36.8MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                   1.3.1                   eb516548c180        7 months ago        40.3MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                      3.3.10                  2c4adeb21b4f        9 months ago        258MB
quay.io/coreos/flannel               v0.10.0-amd64           f0fad859c909        19 months ago       44.6MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                     3.1                     da86e6ba6ca1        20 months ago       742kB
```

root@taeil-linux:~# systemctl status  kubelet

```
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled;     vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-09-06 14:29:25 KST; 4min     19s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
 Main PID: 14470 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 4512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─14470 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-    kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --    kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --    config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --network-    plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 --resolv-con

 9월 06 14:33:44 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:44.800330       14470 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod     9a745ac0a776afabd0d387fd0fcb2f54 ("kube-apiserver-taeil-linux_kube-    system(9a745ac0a776afabd0d387fd0fcb2f54)"), skipping: failed to     "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-apiserver-ta
 9월 06 14:33:44 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:44.897945       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:44 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:44.916566       14470 reflector.go:125]     k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list     *v1.Pod: Get https://10.0.0.152:6443/api/v1/pods?    fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dtaeil-linux&limit=500&resourceVersion=0:     dia
 9월 06 14:33:44 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:44.998190       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:45 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:45.098439       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:45 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:45.198732       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:45 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:45.299052       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:45 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:45.399343       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:45 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:45.499561       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
 9월 06 14:33:45 taeil-linux kubelet[14470]: E0906 14:33:45.599723       14470 kubelet.go:2248] node "taeil-linux" not found
```

root@taeil-linux:~# systemctl status kube-apiserver

```
Unit kube-apiserver.service could not be found.
```

If I try
    docker logs

```
Flag --insecure-port has been deprecated, This flag will be removed in     a future version.
I0906 10:54:19.636649       1 server.go:560] external host was not     specified, using 10.0.0.152
I0906 10:54:19.636954       1 server.go:147] Version: v1.15.3
I0906 10:54:21.753962       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 10 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I0906 10:54:21.753988       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
E0906 10:54:21.754660       1 prometheus.go:55] failed to register     depth metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754701       1 prometheus.go:68] failed to register     adds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754787       1 prometheus.go:82] failed to register     latency metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754842       1 prometheus.go:96] failed to register workDuration metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754883       1 prometheus.go:112] failed to register     unfinished metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754918       1 prometheus.go:126] failed to register     unfinished metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754952       1 prometheus.go:152] failed to register     depth metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.754986       1 prometheus.go:164] failed to register     adds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.755047       1 prometheus.go:176] failed to register     latency metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector     registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.755104       1 prometheus.go:188] failed to register     work_duration metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics     collector registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.755152       1 prometheus.go:203] failed to register     unfinished_work_seconds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate     metrics collector registration attempted
E0906 10:54:21.755188       1 prometheus.go:216] failed to register     longest_running_processor_microseconds metric admission_quota_controller:     duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
I0906 10:54:21.755215       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 10 mutating     admission controller(s) successfully in the following order:     NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesBy    Condition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObj    ectInUseProtection,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I0906 10:54:21.755226       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating     admission controller(s) successfully in the following order:     LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,Validating    AdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I0906 10:54:21.757263       1 client.go:354] parsed scheme: ""
I0906 10:54:21.757280       1 client.go:354] scheme "" not registered,     fallback to default scheme
I0906 10:54:21.757335       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] ccResolverWrapper:     sending new addresses to cc: [{127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}]
I0906 10:54:21.757402       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] balancerWrapper: got     update addr from Notify: [{127.0.0.1:2379 <nil>}]
W0906 10:54:21.757666       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:     addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}.     Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp     127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
I0906 10:54:22.753069       1 client.go:354] parsed scheme: ""
I0906 10:54:22.753118       1 client.go:354] scheme "" not registered,     fallback to default scheme
I0906 10:54:22.753204       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}]
I0906 10:54:22.753354       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] balancerWrapper: got update addr from Notify: [{127.0.0.1:2379 <nil>}]
W0906 10:54:22.753855       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:     addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}.     Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:22.757983       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:23.754019       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:24.430000       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:25.279869       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:26.931974       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:28.198719       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:30.825660       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:     addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}.     Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp     127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:32.850511       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:     addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}.     Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp     127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:36.294749       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:     addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}.     Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp     127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0906 10:54:38.737408       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc:     addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}.     Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp     127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
F0906 10:54:41.757603       1 storage_decorator.go:57] Unable to     create storage backend: config (&{ /registry {[https://127.0.0.1:2379]     /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key     /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt     /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt} true 0xc00063dd40     apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1 <nil> 5m0s 1m0s}), err (dial tcp     127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused)
```

Comment: How did you install kubernetes, is it using a standard distribution, or other standard method of installation such as kubeadm or similar?

Comment: I installed it using kubeadm

Comment: Okay, that helps to understand what you installation is likely to look like.

Regarding the other master components, these are likely running via the kubelet, and hence there won't be any systemd units for them, only for the kubelet itself. You could check the kubelet systemd unit for the flags it's run with, and also look in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` for the component manifests that it will run.

I'm not sure why you can't see the other components listed in `docker ps`, but it's likely they aren't running, as your kubelet and docker logs both show some errors.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `journalctl --all --no-pager -u kubelet.service` and also whatever you ran to get the docker logs before, what was that command?

Comment: I'm really so sorry. I didn't know there was an answer. I left it for a day and the kubernetes environment came back. I don't know why. Thanks for your kind reply :)

Comment: All good,  happy to hear the problem resolved itself for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time no see.

I totally realized how to solve this problem!

If you get an error like this for no reason, you can fix it by:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Perhaps an error occurred when the existing Kubernetes container was rebooted and the newly running container crashed.

```
watch docker ps
```

If you check the container with watch, you can see that kube-apiserver and others are turned off within 1 minute.

So I decided to delete all containers appearing in docker ps -a and it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the comment by @cewood;

> Okay, that helps to understand what you installation is likely to look
>   like. Regarding the other master components, these are likely running
>   via the kubelet, and hence there won't be any systemd units for them,
>   only for the kubelet itself.

With kubeadm install you dont see the services;

as root

```
systemctl start docker
systemctl start kubectl
```

switch to non root user
su nonrootuser -

```
kubectl get pods
```